# jQuery Post Failing On iPad only - why?

Tags: html, jquery, ipad, iis

I have a simple jquery post function, which works well except on iPad over a certain file size (I guess about > 15mb). I have searched far and wide to try and understand why, but I cannot seem to find any reason. I have tested on an iPad mini 2. It works fine for smaller file sizes on iPad, and on larger file sizes for edge, chrome, and firefox. The server is iis8.

The code is very simple:

```
    var image2 = dataUrl.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
    var data2 = JSON.stringify(face);

    $.post("/print/sort", { image2: image2, data2: data2 }, function () {
        location.href = "/print";
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("There has been an error");
    });
```

Can anyone help me understand why this might fail on one device and not another?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no file size limit on IOS mobile Safari. The issue occurred depends on the IOS device memory and image compression algorithm used. There is a certain limitation of the IOS mobile device for loading the file in memory.
Here is a discussion about this topic.
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17131/does-mobile-safari-have-an-image-file-size-limit
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks. That is so useful. I have been looking for this for months, and couldn't find the right keywords to search for it seems.